# angular form validation inside repeated directive

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I've been learning validation forms with angular. I'm using ng-pattern to define the correct format of the input. But after customizing the classes depending on the element's parameters ($valid, $invalid, $error) it requires a lot of code to define the css behaviour related to validation.

So I am exploring the option to build a directive element which could contain all the necessary behaviour.

Here's a plunker illustrating this: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qv6h81MXs4UfhZsgZK2l?p=preview)

Here's the way I would implement the form so I only need to stack the directive elements with their attributes like this : (example here with 2 inputs, but could be more)

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" name="signup_form">

    <input-validation 
    ng-model="register.age" 
    namevalue="age" 
    formvalue="signup_form"
    labeltext="What's your Age?" 
    patterntext="/^[0-9]{1,2}$/" 
    errortext="Age must between 1 and 99" 
    placeholdertext="Enter your Age"></input-validation>

    <input-validation 
    ng-model="register.firstname" 
    namevalue="firstname" 
    formvalue="signup_form"
    labeltext="What's your Name?" 
    patterntext="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}$/" 
    errortext="Name must between 1 and 20 characters long" 
    placeholdertext="Enter your Name"></input-validation>

  </form>
```

With a directive as such :

```
app.directive('inputValidation', function(){
  return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl : 'inputValidation.html',
        scope: {
            inputtext: '=ngModel',
            formvalue: '=',
            namevalue: '=',
            labeltext: '@',
            errortext: '@',
            placeholdertext: '@',
            patterntext: '@',
            autofocusvalue: '@'
        }
    };
});
```

But this doesn't work properly. I understand that the solution could be a combination of compile, require inside the directive, or using the link with the 4th parameter (ctrl) but I'm not sure how to implement this and could use some help.

Comment: You could try my angular validation module instead of all this hassle http://jonsamwell.com/dynamic-angularjs-validation/

Comment: Hi @JonSamwell, thanks for your reply and your link. I'm testing your module. there are 2 things you need to correct on this page http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/ : when you install with bower the library script to insert should be :<script src="bower_components/angular-auto-validate/dist/jcs-auto-validate.min.js"></script> and in the form example, the second ng-model should be model.password. Does your model allow validation on blur?

Comment: also : <div classs="form-row"> are the three 's' a typo? Because it works much better with just 2 :)

Comment: Hi @vonwolf thanks for this - I've just corrected them. Yes the library can do validation on blur by the use of ngModelOptions see http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/#ngmodeloptions - Email me if you have any more questions about it. If you are using Angular 1.3 and above this might be useful to you http://jonsamwell.com/angularjs-set-default-blur-behaviour-on-ngmodeloptions/

Comment: @JonSamwell Wow it's working great. I have reinstalled the module with Bower, it seems you need to update also the bower.json file which is added to bower_components as such : "main": "./dist/jcs-auto-validate.min.js",

Comment: Also, maybe you can post your comment in an answer so I check it as solved. Thanks again and bravo for the great job with this module, it's very easy and straightforward!

Comment: Thanks for all your help with ironing out the document kinks. I've just pushed up another version to bower with everything in and listed you as a contributor (http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/#author).  Let me know if you have any feature suggestions :-)

Comment: Sure thing :) I will be testing it with a more complex form this week, I'll let you know. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try my angular validation module instead of all this hassle http://www.jonsamwell.com/dynamic-angularjs-validation

It favours reducing the complexity of the HTML and all the ng-show expressions you would need in favour of dynamically adding error messages to elements.  This means you can just decorate your elements with validation attributes and not have to worry about anything else.  It is also i18n enabled now :-)